# Generating a signed apk with another keystore

Tags: android, android-studio

I am generating a signed apk through Android Studio, and even when creating a new keystore, Android Studio uses an old keystore. This occurs even by placing the signature data in the gradle. All my apks are coming out with the same SHA1.

Im already push Invalidate Caches and Restart and nothing changes.

Comment: Post your build.gradle file in app level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also do app signing in build.gradle script like this:

```
android {
.....

signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'pass'
            storeFile file('release.keystore')
            storePassword 'pass'
        }

        debug {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'oass'
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'pass'
        }
    }
```